# awk : merge multiple rows into one row per first column record value

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have one text file which contains some records like below,

```
100,a
b
c
101,d,e
f
102,g
103,h
104,i
j
k
```

so,some rows start with number,some rows start with string ,and I want to merge rows which rows are order by number and merge rows like below:

```
100,a,b,c
101,d,e,f
102,g
103,h
104,i,j,k
```

How can I use awk to do this ?
Thanks

Comment: SO is not a code writing service; you're expected to show your effort (eg, research, code); consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, show the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
awk '/^[0-9]/{if(buf){print buf};buf=$0}/^[a-zA-Z]/{buf=buf","$0}END{print buf}' yourfile.txt
```

This will

1. Check if the current line starts with a number `/^[0-9]/`

- If so then it will print out what is stored in variable `buf` if that variable has some value in it `if (buf){print buf}`
- It will then reset the variable `buf` to the value of the current line `buf=$0`

2. If the current line starts with a letter `/^[a-zA-Z]/`

- Then it will add the current line to the value in the variable `buf` with a comma separator `buf=buf","$0`

3. Finally when it reaches the end of the file, it prints out whatever is left in the `buf` variable. `END{print buf}`

Comment: I didn't think about it that in depth @EdMorton Is that a concern from OPs input file or some other awk eccentricity I'm not taking into account?